# "Squared" superscript in ggplot2 yaxis label in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I am plotting a multiple line graph with `ggplot2` and am having trouble labeling the y-axis with mile per second squared. I have tried the command:

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(id)) + labs(y = "Acceleration in m/s^2")
```

and( after searching Stack Overflow):

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(id)) + labs(y = expression ("Acceleration in m/s[2]")
```

In both cases, the label does not create superscript, instead looking exactly like "Acceleration m/s^2". How should this superscript command for a ggplot label be constructed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 + labs(y = expression ("Acceleration in"~m/s^2))
```

Comment: alternatively: `labs(y = bquote("Acceleration in"~m/s^2))`