# Superscripts within ggplot2's axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a graph that has superscripts on the axis instead of displaying unformatted numbers using `ggplot2`. **I know that there are a lot of answers which change the axis label, but not the axis text. I am not trying to change the label of the graph, but the text on the axis.**

Example:

```
x<-c('2^-5','2^-3','2^-1','2^1','2^2','2^3','2^5','2^7','2^9','2^11','2^13')
y<-c('2^-5','2^-3','2^-1','2^1','2^2','2^3','2^5','2^7','2^9','2^11','2^13')
df<-data.frame(x,y)
p<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y),size=4)
p
```

So I would like the x-axis to display the same numbers but without the carrot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `expression` if I recall?

Comment: Or tweak this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920492/squared-superscript-in-ggplot2-yaxis-label-in-r?rq=1

Comment: This is not a duplicate because those are axis labels, this is axis text.

Comment: Are you aware the `x` and `y` are character strings, not numbers? You are plotting factors, meaning, the integers from 1 to 11.

Comment: Yes I designed them like that because if it is numerical then you are plotting numbers like any other graph, I would like to keep them as characters, but you could also have factors.

Comment: So, would you like to evaluate the number equal to the text on the axis or simply remove the caret?

Comment: remove the caret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with functions `scale_x_log2` and `scale_y_log2` that can be found in GitHub package `jrnoldmisc`.

First, install the package.

```
devtools::install_github("jrnold/rubbish")
```

Then, coerce the variables to numeric. I wil work with a copy of the original dataframe.

```
df1 <- df
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x){
  x <- as.character(x)
  sapply(x, function(.x)eval(parse(text = .x)))
})
```

Now, graph it.

```
library(jrnoldmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(scales)

a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = 4)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_log2(limits = c(0.01, NA), 
                labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^x, n = 10)) +
  scale_y_log2(limits = c(0.01, NA),
                labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^x, n = 10))
a + annotation_logticks(base = 2)
```

[image]

**Edit.**

Following the discussion in the comments, here are the two other ways that were seen to give different axis labels.

1. Axis labels every tick mark. Set `limits = c(1.01, NA)` and function argument `n = 11`, an odd number.
2. Axis labels on odd number exponents. Keep `limits = c(0.01, NA)`, change to `function(x) 2^(x - 1), n = 11`.

Just the instructions, no plots.

The first.

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = 4)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_log2(limits = c(1.01, NA), 
                labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^(x), n = 11)) +
  scale_y_log2(limits = c(1.01, NA),
                labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^(x), n = 11))
a + annotation_logticks(base = 2)
```

And the second.

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, size = 4)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_log2(limits = c(0.01, NA), 
               labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
               breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^(x - 1), n = 11)) +
  scale_y_log2(limits = c(0.01, NA),
               labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)),
               breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^(x - 1), n = 11))
a + annotation_logticks(base = 2)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the tick marks on the odd numbers or every tick mark instead of only the even ones?

Comment: @JackArmstrong Yes, it is, I have just tested `limits = c(1.01, NA)` on both `sclae_*_log2` calls and it now prints on every tick mark.

Comment: Instead of using limits, within breaks, = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^(x-1), n = 10))

Comment: @JackArmstrong You are absolutely right, didn't think of that. But it will give the labels on odd exponents only, with me `limits` gives them on every tick mark.

Comment: @JackArmstrong OK, got it. I had changed argument `n` in `function(x) 2^(x), n = 11` to an odd number. Plus `limits = c(1.01, NA)` it gives labels  on every tick mark. Should I edit the answer with this?

Comment: If you want to with other possible ways, sure. No need for pictures I think. People should be able to read.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:
A purely `base` approach:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character)->new_df
res<-unlist(Map(function(x) eval(parse(text=x)),new_df$x))#replace with y for y
to_use<-unlist(lapply(res,as.expression))
split_text<-strsplit(gsub("\\^"," ",names(to_use))," ")
join_1<-as.numeric(sapply(split_text,"[[",1)) #tidyr::separate might help, less robust for numeric(I think)
join_2<-as.numeric(sapply(split_text,"[[",2))
to_use_1<-sapply(seq_along(join_1),function(x) parse(text=paste(join_1[x],"^",
                                                join_2[x])))
```

The above can be reduced to less step, I posted the stepwise approach I took. The result for only `x`, the same can be done for `y`:

```
new_df %>%   
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),size=4)+
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=df$x,labels=to_use_1)#replace with y and scale_y_discrete for y
```

Plot:
[image]

**Original and erroneous answer**:

I have deviated from standard `tidyverse` practice by using `$`, you can replace it with `.` and it might work although in this case it's not really important since the focus is on labels.:

```
    library(dplyr)
   df %>% 
          mutate(new_x=gsub("\\^"," ",x),
                 new_y=gsub("\\^"," ",y))->new_df
        new_df %>%   
        ggplot()+
          geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),size=4)+
         scale_x_discrete(breaks=x,labels=new_df$new_x)+
          scale_y_discrete(breaks=y,labels=new_df$new_y)
```

Comment: I think this is a good start, but now the numbers are out of order

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate how?

Comment: Well, 2^11 comes before 2^3 for example.

Comment: Not sure why we have different results though. Are you using the data in the question or some other data? Been a few days since I looked at this so might need to see the code you're using and/or data.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a function to the `labels` argument of the `scale_x_***` and `scale_y_***` functions to generate labels with superscripts (or other formatting). See examples below.

```
library(jrnoldmisc)
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(x=2^seq(-5,5,2),
               y=2^seq(-5,5,2))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),size=2)  +
  scale_x_log2(breaks=2^seq(-5,5,2),
               labels=function(x) parse(text=paste("2^",round(log2(x),2))))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),size=2)  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2^-5, 2^seq(1,5,2)),
                     labels=function(x) parse(text=paste("2^",round(log2(x),2))))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),size=2)  +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=10^seq(-1,1,1),
                labels=function(x) parse(text=paste("10^",round(log10(x),2))))
```

[image]